# In a Scala class declaration, does the "with" keyword specify an "is-a" relationship?

Tags: scala, inheritance, mixins, traits

I would like to gain some intuition for the use of the `with` keyword in Scala.

A coworker wrote a trait which completely implemented a self contained function, and then used `with` to mix it into several classes.  This practice just felt wrong to me, and a conversation started.  Here's the way he did it using a `trait` with `with`:

```
trait Download { def download(url: String): String = {...} }
class DataSet(...) extends Super(...) with Download {
  def method(...) { ... download(url) ... }
}
```

I came to Scala from Java and C++, and always thought of `with` as giving me back the multiple inheritance I missed from C++, and accordingly have only used it in "is-a" kinds of ways (like `extends`).  He argued that the language designers could have used a more obvious reserved word like `isa`, or repeated uses of `extends` instead of `with` if that's what they intended.  He felt that `with` was intended to let him out of the normal inheritance guidelines, and said that he'd seen it used that way in some popular libraries.

I have an open mind about this:  How was `with` intended to be used?  If common usage is other than was intended, how is `with` most commonly used?  Is this really just a style issue?

My strongest argument against `with` in the example above is that `with` lets you hold a reference to an instance, such as `val d: Download = new DataSet(...)`, which provides a `d.download(...)` method which doesn't have anything to do with `DataSet` at all.  That is:  it's not the case that DataSet "is-a" download.  I'm primarily interested in guidance in using `with`.

Comment: Properly speaking (but in distinct contrast to common usage), is-a is a relationship between instances and types while a-kind-of is a relationship between types (it's also known as the subtype relation). Sadly, the distinction gets blurred almost universally.

Comment: I think your problem is that Download should be named Downloader. Then it could make sense to say that a RemoteDataSet is a Downloader and thus has a download method.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two approaches to this:

1. Considering it inheritance, which it technical is. Thus your argument holds and you should use it sparingly  as you said. I most of the time follow this approach.
2. Consider it a way of composing stuff into a class or object. Just as you I'm not fond of this, but it does happen a lot in many libraries. One example would be ScalaTest which has many traits like [BeforeAndAfterAll](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.0/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.html). Even Martin Odersky (and/or his team) use it this way in their Coursera courses. So it is a sanctioned practice. Is it a good idea? I don't know, I guess time will tell. At least it doesn't have the drawback of inheritance in Java, that you can only use one thing via inheritance and have to do something else with the rest. That might limit some of the problems that made most of us avoid inheritance in many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** *in response to the question change*

Your first example is indeed inheritance. `extends` denotes inheritance here just as it does in C++

`with` also denotes inheritance, though there's another way to view it.  The declaration can be parsed as:

```
class DataSet(...) extends [ Super(...) with Download ]
```

You read `Super with Download` as a single type containing the linearized members of both `Super` and `Download`, and *that* is what you're extending.  It makes sense to think this way as you can write:

```
val x: Super with Download = new DataSet(...)
```

This is a very tight coupling where the inherited `download()` method is now exposed as a method of `DataSet`.

It most certainly *does* represent an `is-a` relationship; if you need an instance of `Download` then you can successfully supply an instance of `DataSet` to do the job.

So `DataSet` is-a `Download`.  Although this kind of usage is generally frowned upon by many purists of class-based object oriented languages.  The primary objection is that you should always use the weakest form of coupling possible *(a practice encouraged, in part, because of the improvement that it yields in C++ compile times)*

If you want to inherit a lot of methods, this is the easiest way.  It's rather handy if a class has a lot of autogenerated code mixed in with some custom logic.  You just autogenerate a trait and inherit from that.  It's also used to great effect in e.g. ScalaTest to rapidly import a bunch of utility methods & types.

---

However, I don't like it in this use-case.

Why?  Because with a name like `Download`, this thing is clearly intended to use a network connection, which is a Particularly Bad Idea(tm) when unit testing; and you've got no way to substitute alternative behaviour in a mock version.

Your best bet would be to supply an instance of `Download` via the `DataSet` constructor.  It can still be a singleton and you can use a default param to avoid boilerplate:

```
trait Download {
  def apply(url: String): String
}
object DefaultDownload extends Download {
  def apply(url: String): String = ...
}

class DataSet(..., download: Download = DefaultDownload) extends Super(...) {
  def method(...) { ... download(url) ... }
}
```

Comment: This didn't really offer any guidance on the use of `with`, it seems actually that you would probably say that neither `extends` nor `with` denotes an "is-a", inheritance style relationship.  Rather that they are both just ways to add a bunch of methods to a class all at once...  I do agree though, that in this specific example, it would be better to pass in the `Download` than to use `with` to get it from the trait.

Comment: My first sentence stated that it was inheritance. `extends` and `with` are both inheritance.

Comment: I've altered the question, removing the alternatives as I think they were just distracting from what I was actually interested in.  If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the use of `with` is inheritance, but that inheritance does not model an "is-a" relationship, is that correct?  I can accept that, though i have a differing opinion, and would like to hear from others with other opinions.

Comment: Download could also explicitely require the implementing type to provide it with a network connection either by declaring an abstract method to retrieve a network connection to be implemented by the extending type or by using an explicitely typed self reference http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/124

Comment: @Jean - It *could*, but that's heading entirely the wrong direction relatve to simplicity and readability.

Comment: I imagine the actual use case is more complex than the one presented in the example. I simply wanted to provide pointers as to ways to split such complexity further.

Comment: Yes, this example was just to act as the context for conversation.  @Kevin - Thank's for that alternate parsing of the type, that is _exactly_ the kind of thing I was hoping to gain from responses to my question.  It gives me an intuition that will help me in the future.